# Geopy Nominatim SSLCertVerificationError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ssl-certificate, geopy, nominatim

I am trying to use Nominatim to do geocoding but get an SSL Error of:

[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)

The error happens after I run this chunk of code in jupyter notebook:

```
nom.geocode("3995 23rd St, San Francisco, CA 94114")
```

I have had SSL errors before, but they only appeared when I ran a pip install without having a trusted host.

My OS is windows and I am running my code in Jupyter notebook from anaconda. I am on Python 3.9.13.

I'm imagining that this error has to be coming from the fact that I am using anaconda.

Below are all my chunks of code from my Jupyer Notebook:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org geopy
```

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
```

```
nom=Nominatim(user_agent="test")
```

```
nom.geocode("3995 23rd St, San Francisco, CA 94114")
```

I am getting the error from the last chuck.

I'm sorry if this question is obvious but I haven't been able to find the solution yet.