# using geopy and using Nominatim I get certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, geopy, nominatim

running windows 10 with Python 3.10.
I have been running into an SSL error when I attempt to use the Nominatim service. I do not see this error with ArcGIS service.

Example code:

```
import certifi
import ssl

import geopy.geocoders
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.geocoders import ArcGIS

ctx = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
geopy.geocoders.options.default_ssl_context = ctx

print('')
print('Trying Nominatim')
try:
    geolocator_NOM = Nominatim(user_agent="NewApp314", timeout=10)
    location_NOM = geolocator_NOM.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')

    print(f'Location Address: {location_NOM.address}')
    print(f'Location Latitude: {location_NOM.latitude}')
    print(f'Location Longitude: {location_NOM.longitude}')
except Exception as error:
    print(f'Error in Nominatim: {error}')


print('')
print('Trying ArcGIS:')
try:
    geolocator_ARC = ArcGIS()
    location_ARC = geolocator_ARC.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')

    print(f'Location Address: {location_ARC.address}')
    print(f'Location Latitude: {location_ARC.latitude}')
    print(f'Location Longitude: {location_ARC.longitude}')
except Exception as error:
    print(f'Error in ArcGIS: {error}')
```

When I run the code I receive the following output:

```
Trying Nominatim:
Error in Nominatim: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway%2C+Mountain+View%2C+CA&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by 
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)')))

Trying ArcGIS:
Location Address: 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, California, 94043
Location Latitude: 37.421976010046
Location Longitude: -122.084524027111
```

I've looked all over for solutions and noticed a couple similar errors on stack Overflow, but no solutions:

[Geopy Nominatim SSLCertVerificationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75339962/geopy-nominatim-sslcertverificationerror)

Similar error, but solution did not fix issue identified
[Python ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560143/python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed)